# Android 2.2 Tablet Camera Issue

Tags: android, camera, android-2.2-froyo

I am having an issue with the camera class on android 2.2 tablet. The problem is that when activating the camera preview, I see static as seen below:

http://i81.photobucket.com/albums/j237/bwyyoung/Develop/IMG_0119.jpg

The static is seen below, even when I operate the camera class on full screen.

My code for the camera is below:

```
public class OoohaPrototypeActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private CameraPreview mPreview;
Camera mCamera;
int numberOfCameras;
int cameraCurrentlyLocked;

// The first rear facing camera
int defaultCameraId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this);
     setContentView(mPreview);
}
```

I face the same issue even after restarting the tablet. The tablet's normal camera app preview works fine though. The CameraPreview class is the same one seen in 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old thread, but I might be of assistance, does your tablet has a front facing camera only ? the `camera.open();` will return null on if you're tablet does not have a rear facing camera.

Therefore what is probably best is to check for a null, and open the default camera using something like

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

and handle the result of this call